# Is there a way to use glsl file on Vulkan in java

Tags: java, glsl, vulkan

I was just wondering if there’s a way to use Glsl shader file on Vulkan in java

I try to use the shader C Library on Java but i couldn’t find any documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should compile GLSL shaders into SPIRV binaries using ShaderSPIRVUtils. A guide for this can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Naitsirc98/Vulkan-Tutorial-Java).